# Meaning of いるとin 弥生時代にはいると…

Tags: japanese-to-english

So I found this sentence:

> 弥生時代にはいると食事の内容が大きく変化しました

I understand its meaning, something like

> In the Yayoi period, the food content changed a lot

However, 'In the Yayoi period' is a free translation, because I don't really know what いると means. Does と work as 'when'? How would you translate that? A literal translation would also help for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb after 弥生時代に is 入る【はいる】 ("to enter (an age/season)"), not いる.

> #### [入る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8B_%28%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%29/)
>
> 11 ある時期・地点に至る。「雨期に―・る」「月が山の陰に―・る」

Therefore the literal translation is:

> 弥生時代に入る【はいる】と...
> After entering the Yayoi period, ...
> When the Yayoi period began, ...

Comment: Oh, I get it. I thought about it but I discarded that because according to my dictionary 入る is not written in kana, though the sentence makes sense like that, I guess. Thank you

Comment: @M364 It's definitely better to write this in kanji, but IMEs aren't perfect, and people don't always bother to fix something like this...